# How remove elemts of array from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How remove elements of array from another array?
I have first array ["a" "b" "c"].
And second array [["a", "e"], ["e", "b", "c"], ["a","c"]].

How remove elements of first array from second array?

as a result, get [["e"], ["e"], []].

Comment: what effort have you made?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const first = [
  ["a", "e"],
  ["e", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "c"]
]
const second = ["a", "b", "c"]

const result = first.map(el => {
  return el.filter(elem => !second.includes(elem))
})

console.log(result)
```